# Can't connect to cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

When I try to run cqlsh I obtain the error:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': TypeError('ref() does not take keyword arguments',)})
```

I correctly execute ./bin/cassandra
if i test ./bin/nodetool status I get:

## Datacenter: datacenter1

Status=Up/Down

|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack

UN  127.0.0.1  205,67 KiB  256          100,0%            d260f9df-75c1-47af-b7ee-d7a9ad367ead  rack1

here is some parameters of cassandra.yaml file:

```
seed_provider:
# Addresses of hosts that are deemed contact points. 
# Cassandra nodes use this list of hosts to find each other and learn
# the topology of the ring.  You must change this if you are running
# multiple nodes!
- class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
  parameters:
      # seeds is actually a comma-delimited list of addresses.
      # Ex: "<ip1>,<ip2>,<ip3>"
      - seeds: "127.0.0.1" 
storage_port: 700
listen_address: localhost
native_transport_port: 9042
```

I already tried:

```
export CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED=true
pip install cassandra-driver
```

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Can post the code you are using to try to connect? Is this on the same machine?

Comment: I am just executing in a terminal under /apache-cassandra-3.7/bin  the command ./cqlsh